# How to keep track of source code call stack

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to re-implement a C++ code in Go. Specifically, I'm focused on [`meshToVolume` tool](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openvdb/blob/d1969c55d584dff74f005c5647e27c91a068107f/openvdb/tools/MeshToVolume.h#L3118) of OpenVDB library.

As shown by a manually-prepared [code flow screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4UWq.jpg), even a rough call stack map is pretty perplexing.

I'm looking for a tool to help me keep track of call stack and the code flow. So far:

- I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16938700/3405291) and tried out BOUML, but it didn't help
- Also, OpenVDB has a [Doxygen](https://www.openvdb.org/documentation/doxygen/annotated.html), but I couldn't get much help regarding keeping track of code flow and call stack

Can anybody suggest a helpful tool/method?

Comment: check if this applies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c

Comment: I recommend not using a code flow visualization tool at all. They quickly get very complex, defeating their purpose. Try porting the classes and functions of meshToVolume one by one.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Thanks! I'm going to give it a try. I appreciate any tool which might possibly help a bit =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Doxygen, I could finally visualize **call graph**!

#### Approach

[Downloaded](https://www.doxygen.nl/download.html) and installed Doxygen. Then ran Doxywizard i.e. Doxygen GUI front-end. OpenVDB has a `doc` directory which is set as the working directory from which Doxygen will run.

[image: Working directories]

Without selecting these options, call graphs didn't get generated for me:

[image]

I have Graphviz DOT language installed on my machine. There I can use it to generate call graphs:

[image: Dot tool]

Finally, Doxygen generates the output HTML accessible at:

`file:///C:/Users/m3/repos/doxygen-output/html/index.html`

[image]

Dependency graph sample:

[image: Dependency graph sample]